# How do you rename the elements of a list when they are nested within another list using R's purrr package?

Tags: r, list, rename, purrr, r-highcharter

The NBER dates recessions by their peak and trough.  The json version of the data is [here](http://data.nber.org/data/cycles/business_cycle_dates.json). A simple version looks like this:

```
list_old <- list(list(peak = "", trough = "1854-12-01"), list(peak = "1857-06-01", trough = "1858-12-01"))
```

In order for `plotBands` to be displayed in the `highcharter` package, the lists must be renamed so that "peak" becomes "start" and "trough" becomes "end".  The resulting list would look like this:

```
list_new <- list(list(start = "", end = "1854-12-01"), list(start = "1857-06-01", end = "1858-12-01"))
```

Is there a way to achieve this using the tidyverse in R?  (I've been looking in the `purrr` package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `lapply` to rename each list.

```r
lapply(list_old, \(x) {
  names(x) <- c("start", "end")
  x
  }
)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$start
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> [[1]]$end
#> [1] "1854-12-01"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$start
#> [1] "1857-06-01"
#> 
#> [[2]]$end
#> [1] "1858-12-01"
```

You could use `purrr::map()` if you'd rather a tidy solution. If using `purrr`, from @Donald Seinen's comment, can also use `set_names()`

```r
library(purrr)

map(
  list_old,
  set_names,
  c("start", "end")
)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$start
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> [[1]]$end
#> [1] "1854-12-01"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$start
#> [1] "1857-06-01"
#> 
#> [[2]]$end
#> [1] "1858-12-01"
```